# Laravel blank page on live server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've tried to deploy a laravel project on my live server. I have a git repository on my server (not public) which got a git hook to deploy my changes to the live site if i need it. Locally I checked out the git repo and created a new laravel project via composer (command line), i than add every file to git, commit it and push it to my server. On my server, i got a virtual host pointing to the public folder of my laravel project.
The default laravel page is working on my localhost, but not on my server (blank page). I've also set the right access rights for app and app/storage (write access). When I look into my apache error log, it says:

> [Thu Mar 19 22:39:46 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/example.com/public_html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/example.com/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

I really don't know what I can try to get this working. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run `composer install` on the live server yet?

Comment: The `composer.json` file defines the 3rd party libraries used by the application. There is no need to store all that 3rd party code in your application's repo, so it's ignored by git (see the `.gitignore` file). So when you cloned your repo onto the live server the libraries weren't present. `composer install` downloads and installs the libraries. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a permissions problem for your cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check `laravel` support `php version` in composer.json file

i think `php version issue`.